# Fetch all mongoid documents based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

class name is Usersdata

In mongo

```
{id:100,createdby:900,.......}
{id:200,createdby:900,.......}
{id:300,createdby:900,.......}
{id:400,createdby:800,.......}
{id:500,createdby:800,.......}
```

I want to fetch all records having createdby=900..I tried this

```
Userdata.where(createdby: 900)
```

But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.where` returns a `Criteria`. You have to iterate over that to get all the results, the simplest being `Userdata.where(createdby:900).to_a` to get an array of the results.

Comment: Each array member will definitely be a `Userdata` object. I suppose in your application you can simply access each member like `member.id` or `member.created_by`. If you really wanted the response like you mention, you can use `map` as in `result.map { |r| {id:r.id,created_by:r.created_by} }` though I'm not sure if it's a good solution.